# Shading the region bound by two graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

How do I shade the region bound by the standard parabola and the square root function?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}



\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}



\begin{document}

\raisebox{0mm}[0mm][0mm]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=2.25in, height=2.25in, axis equal image, axis on top, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2,xmax=4, domain=-2:4,
    ymin=-0.75,ymax=4,
    restrict y to domain=-0.75:4,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x},ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]

%The graphs of the square root function and the standard parabola are plotted.
\addplot[samples=501, domain=-2:2] {x^2};
\addplot[samples=501, domain=0:4] {sqrt(x)};


%Coordinate A is the point of tangency to the graph of the standard parabola, and B is the
%x-intercept of the tangent line.
\coordinate (A) at (-15/8,225/64);
\coordinate (B) at (-15/16,0);

%Coordinate P is the point of tangency to the graph of the square root function, and Q is
%the y-intercept of the tangent line.
\coordinate (P) at (15/4,{sqrt(15/4)});
\coordinate (Q) at (0,{1/4*sqrt(15)});

\end{axis}


%A "pin" is drawn to A.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (A) -- ($(A)!0.5cm!-90:(B)$) node[anchor=west, inner sep=0,  font=\scriptsize]{\makebox[0pt][r]{$y=x^{2}$}};

%A "pin" is drawn to P.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (P) -- ($(P)!0.5cm!90:(Q)$);
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(P)!0.4cm!90:(Q)$){\makebox[0pt][l]{$y=\sqrt{x}$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the code for a typical plot seen in a Calculus course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a standard task for the `fillbetween` library.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}



\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}


\begin{document}

\raisebox{0mm}[0mm][0mm]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=2.25in, height=2.25in, axis equal image, axis on top, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2,xmax=4, domain=-2:4,
    ymin=-0.75,ymax=4,
    restrict y to domain=-0.75:4,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x},ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]

%The graphs of the square root function and the standard parabola are plotted.
\addplot[samples=501, domain=-2:2,name path=parabola] {x^2};
\addplot[samples=501, domain=0:4,name path=root] {sqrt(x)};

\addplot[red!10] fill between [of=parabola and root, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
%Coordinate A is the point of tangency to the graph of the standard parabola, and B is the
%x-intercept of the tangent line.
\coordinate (A) at (-15/8,225/64);
\coordinate (B) at (-15/16,0);

%Coordinate P is the point of tangency to the graph of the square root function, and Q is
%the y-intercept of the tangent line.
\coordinate (P) at (15/4,{sqrt(15/4)});
\coordinate (Q) at (0,{1/4*sqrt(15)});

\end{axis}


%A "pin" is drawn to A.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (A) -- ($(A)!0.5cm!-90:(B)$) node[anchor=west, inner sep=0,  font=\scriptsize]{\makebox[0pt][r]{$y=x^{2}$}};

%A "pin" is drawn to P.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (P) -- ($(P)!0.5cm!90:(Q)$);
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(P)!0.4cm!90:(Q)$){\makebox[0pt][l]{$y=\sqrt{x}$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see the response that I posted.

Comment: @Adelyn I just looked at your follow-up question. As far as I can see, the shading does appear there. Is that correct? (As far as I can see the main issue is that the dimension of your left minipage is to generous, so you may just reduce `6in` to `3.5in` unless you want to use other methods such as `wrapfig`.)

Comment: The shading is not there. I replaced `red!10` with `black` and nothing happens - the region between the two graphs is not shaded. Do I have to manually download a package onto the hard drive?

Comment: Regarding the follow-up question, I would prefer not to change the margins for any `minipage` environment. What would you suggest for a `wrapfig`?

Comment: @Adelyn I am sorry, this is the output I am getting on my machine. And I have no idea why it is not there on your machine.  And as for your follow-up question, I guess it is better if you place requests there.  If you do not accept this answer because it does not give you the desired output, that's perfectly fine. But I cannot really make statements on answers that I did not write.